# Multiple Joins LINQ Query performance

Tags: performance, linq

I'm new to LINQ and have very little knowledge.
I have the following complex query. it runs 3 or 4 times slower than the stored procedure which i translated to LINQ.

any tips for me to make it run faster?

```
var result = from a in db.A 
    join al in db.AL.Where(q => q.CurrentLocation == 1) on a.AID equals al.AID into tmp_al
    from al in tmp_al.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join l in db.Lon al.LID equals l.LID into tmp_l
    from l in tmp_l.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join r in db.R on l.RID equals r.RID into tmp_r
    from r in tmp_r.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join b in db.B on r.BID equals b.BID into tmp_b
    from b in tmp_b.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join ap in db.AP.Where(q => q.CurrentProtocol == 1) on a.AID equals ap.AID into tmp_ap
    from ap in tmp_ap.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join p in db.P on ap.PID equals p.PID into tmp_p
    from p in tmp_p.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join s in db.S on a.SID equals s.SID into tmp_s
    from s in tmp_s.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join ans in db.AS on a.ASID equals ans.ASID into tmp_ans
    from ans in tmp_ans.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join pr in db.P on p.PI equals pr.PID into tmp_pr
    from pr in tmp_pr.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where a.Active == 1
    group a by new { a.Active, pr.LN, pr.FN, b.BN, r.RID, r.R1, p.PN, s.S1, ans.AS1 }
      into grp
      orderby grp.Key.BN, grp.Key.R1, grp.Key.PN, grp.Key.S1, grp.Key.AS1
      select new
      {
          PIName = grp.Key.LN + " " + grp.Key.FN,
          BN = grp.Key.BN,
          RID = grp.Key.RID,
          R = grp.Key.R1,
          PN = grp.Key.PN,
          S = grp.Key.S1,
          AS = grp.Key.AS1,
          NumberOA = grp.Count()
      };
```

Thanks for your answers. @Albin Sunnanbo: i dont know how to check the execution plans. my LINQ runs correctly and produces the required output. it is just slow. I would like to speeden it up.                           @usr: the original sql is as follows: 
 sorry about the silly table names. the original code is confidential. so i'm not posting the complete table names.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[report_CBRP] --  
AS
SELECT LN + ' ' + FN As PIN, BN, R.RID, R, PN, 
S, AS, COUNT(*) As NOA 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN AL 
ON A.AID = AL.AID 
AND AL.CL = 1
LEFT JOIN L 
ON AL.LID = L.LID 
LEFT JOIN R
ON L.RID = R.RID 
LEFT JOIN B 
ON R.BID = B.BID 
LEFT JOIN AP
ON A.AID = AP.AID 
AND AP.CPl = 1
LEFT JOIN P 
ON AP.PID = P.PID 
LEFT JOIN S 
ON A.SID = S.SID 
LEFT JOIN AS
ON A.ASID = AS.ASID
LEFT JOIN P
ON P.PI = P.PID 
GROUP BY A.A, LN , FN , B.BN, R.RID, R.R, P.PN, 
S.S, AS.AS 
HAVING A.A = 1 
ORDER BY B.BN, R.R, P.PN, S, AS
GO
```

Comment: Are you trying to do a bunch of left outer joins?

Comment: yes. the stored procedure has a bunch of left outer joins. i'm converting it to LINQ.

Comment: Have you compared the generated SQL (check in SQL Profiler) with the stored procedure? Have you compared the execution plans of the LINQ query with the stored procedure?

Comment: That query *should* translate nicely. You have correctly constructed it and not made any trivial mistakes. Please post the SQL.

Comment: After your edit: these are not _outer_ joins. That's a huge difference. Remove the `DefaultIfEmpty`s from your linq statements.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: My mistake. i didnt read the comment properly. i was mentioning joins not outer joins.  what will removing DefaultIfEmpty() achieve? i already mentioned i'm a novice. i just read tutorials and constructed my linq query. so please explain.

Comment: Removing `DefaultIfEmpty()` will create inner joins. (As your sproc has).

Comment: @GertArnold looks like left outer joins to me in the SP

Comment: @Magnus S**t, you're right, forgot that `OUTER` is implicit there. I think the OP just has to face that EF is just slower. Probably should just hang on to the sproc.

Comment: Which ORM are you using? Is the time spent executing the generated SQL, or is the time spent while generating the SQL? I've had it before where EF has had exponential growth in the time taken on SQL generation for joins (have now moved to NHibernate which has much quicker SQL generation)

Comment: I am interested in what EF actually generates for this query. If you don't have access to SQL Profiler, you can dump the generated SQL for a query by doing `(query as System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery).ToTraceString()`. Try to do that and compare it with the stored procedure.

Comment: Looks like **Inner Join** instead of **Left Join**

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're doing SQL hard life here.

1. In general, try to avoid so many joins, but rather break them into few small queries.
2. More than that, you're performing a group by which in itself is an expensive operation, let alone with so many columns
3. I've noticed that you're joining **all** the columns in each table. Try to select only the relevant columns.
4. Also noticed that few of the tables aren't used in the group by like *al*, *ap* and *l*. Do you need them at all??
5. Use AsNoTracking() for readonly data from EF. In that way you speed up things.
6. Use SQL Views